# When I import socket in python, why does it skip socket.bind?

Tags: python, sockets

I think every method except bind is in there. I type:

```
import socket
socket.bind
```

in the python command prompt, and get "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bind'".

If I do:

```
from socket import bind
```

I get "ImportError: cannot import name bind"

Otherwise, dir(socket) returns 297 and everything else seems to work fine. Like I have socket.socket, socket.setsockopt, etc. Just bind doesn't exist.

I am in Mint 16 running python 2.7.5+. The same happens in python 3.3.2+, and in Python 2.7.3 on an ubuntu 12.04 vm on the same machine.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bind` is a method of a `socket` *object*, not the module

The following is an example of where `bind` is used, after creating a `socket` object:

Taken from docs on [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example)

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem. For what it's worth, this all spawned from a typo where I referred to my socket object as 'socket' instead of its actual name. I guess I learned something about how python organizes names of things today.

Comment: @user3217070, ah, much like the ol' `list = [1, 2, 3]` snafu!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here as I don't use the `socket` module as often as you probably do, but it seems `bind` is the function of the class `socket` in the module `socket`. So to access it, you have to do:

```
>>> socket.socket.bind
<unbound method _socketobject.bind>
```

Comment: Actually, it's an instance method. So without a socket object it's practically useless.

Answer (score 0):

`bind` is a method of `socket.socket`, not a function in the module.

```
s = socket.socket(...)
s.bind()
```

So only once you created a socket, you can bind it to an address.

Reference: [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind).

Hope this helps!